# Trying to install ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I have Ruby 2.1.4 on my machine, installed using RVM.  I need to work on a project using Ruby 1.9.3, but when I try to install using RVM I get the following error on my machine:

```
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.26.3', you are using older version '1.26.0'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
ruby-1.9.3-p550 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p550..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p550.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p550 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p550, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p550 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p550 to /Users/Jean/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p550....
ruby-1.9.3-p550 - #applying patch /Users/Jean/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p550 - #configuring.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Jean/.rvm/log/1417082976_ruby-1.9.3-p550/configure.log
[2014-11-27 11:09:58] ./configure
current path: /Users/Jean/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p550
GEM_HOME=/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4:/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Jean/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p550':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

And this is my config.log file:

```
[2014-11-27 11:09:58] ./configure
current path: /Users/Jean/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p550
GEM_HOME=/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Jean/.rvm/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4:/Users/Jean/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Jean/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p550':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: In my experience, "WARNING: unrecognized options" is normally a problem with GCC. What OS you on? From the references to Darwin I'm assuming a Mac. Are you using brew or macports? What happens when you run `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Hey peter, xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: What does `gcc --version` and `which gcc` give you? try `brew install gcc` if you have brew installed.

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: /usr/bin/gcc but I get the same error after update the command line tools

Comment: Which package manager are you using? Generally the best idea is to upgrade gcc with `macports` or `brew`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65751/discussion-between-peter-souter-and-jean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed [in chat,](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65751/discussion-between-peter-souter-and-jean) this seemed to fix it:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=`which gcc`
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed ruby 1.9.3 using the following command:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install x-code and verify that has been updated.

Open it, go to preferences, downloads tabs, and click "Install next" to the Command Line Tools package.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the version of RVM on your machine.

```
  rvm get stable
```